# Create new data frame column from past values

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
dt   dtPr   id    val
99    98     a     10
98    97     a     9
97    96     a     8
99    98     b     20
98    97     b     19
97    96     b     18
```

What is the most efficient way to create another data frame column that shows "prior value" based on the two dates?  Prior value should equal the `val` where `dtPr = dt` for a given `id`.  I could do this easily in SQL but I"m unsure about the most efficient approach in R.

Example output:

```
dt   dtPr   id    val   valPr
99    98     a     10    9
98    97     a     9     8
97    96     a     8     NULL
99    98     b     20    19
98    97     b     19    18
97    96     b     18    NULL
```

Code to generate sample data frame:

```
a <- c(99,98,97,99,98,97)
b <- c(98,97,96,98,97,96)
c <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
d <- c(10,9,8,20,19,18)
e <- data.frame(dt = a, dtPr = b, id = c, val = d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` will be probably the *most efficient way*, as it updates/creates column by reference (without creating copies)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(e)[, valPr := c(val[-1], NA), by = id]
e
#    dt dtPr id val valPr
# 1: 99   98  a  10     9
# 2: 98   97  a   9     8
# 3: 97   96  a   8    NA  
# 4: 99   98  b  20    19
# 5: 98   97  b  19    18
# 6: 97   96  b  18    NA
```

Although the question is a bit unclear. Are there any cases in your real data when `dt` and `dtPr` are not consecutive by row?

---

If you really meant a recursive join, i.e. dates are not always in consecutive rows, you could create an index using `match` and then extract those values

```
setDT(e)[, Indx := match(dtPr, dt), by = id][, valPr := val[Indx], by = id]
e
#    dt dtPr id val Indx valPr
# 1: 99   98  a  10    2     9
# 2: 98   97  a   9    3     8
# 3: 97   96  a   8   NA    NA
# 4: 99   98  b  20    2    19
# 5: 98   97  b  19    3    18
# 6: 97   96  b  18   NA    NA
```

Comment: Since the input was numeric, wouldn't it have been more appropriate to return a numeric vector?

Comment: @BondedDust, maybe, but his desired output contained `NULL` so I thought `""` is more similar to it than `NA`, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Think sometimes people need to be protected from their own folly.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer, please provide some feedback, as your question is a bit vogue

Comment: This works really well.  Thank you for the data table suggestion.  I'm using it more and more lately.

I ended up just doing some sorting before applying the table.  This was helpful for some other operations that are more complicated than the example.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the data is sorted in whatever order you need, and recognizing that it should be NA rather than NULL which is used in a dataframe column:

```
e$valPr  <- with( e , ave(val, id, FUN=function(x) c(tail(x,-1),NA) ) )
```

The `ave` function operates on a vector, breaks the vector into segments defined by the second argument, "id" in this case, and returns a vector of the same length as the original. It can be used to create group sums, group averages, or as in this case group-specific vectors constructed by shifting or other operations involving indexing or ordering as long as the result is the same length as the input within each group.

Comment: the way how `ave` works looks the same idea as `ddply`. vote up from `stats`

Comment: @B.Mr.W., `ddply` is an external package, while `ave` is base R. So the opposite is true. Also, I doubt that BondedDust was trying to mimic `ddply`, so your comment is essentially pointless

Comment: @B.Mr.W. The 'plyr'-package functions had performance issues, which I think is the reason hadley developed the 'dplyr'-package. I didn't find the formula interface that plyr functions provided to be much of an improvement over the equivalent base functions, but I think his 'dplyr' work is going to be very useful to the R world in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but function blurf calls the global variable `e` ...

```
blurf=function(x){   temp=as.data.frame(t(x))   
    result=as.numeric(e$val[as.character(e$id)==as.character(temp$id) & e$dt==temp$dtPr]) 
    if (identical(result, numeric(0))) result=NA   
    result 
}

e$valPr=apply(e,1,blurf)
```